# Which objects are allowed in a method

Tags: java, class

I have a general question. Let's say I have the following structure:

```
interface IFirst{}
class A implements IFirst{}
class B extends A{}
```

And furthermore the following class:

```
class TestClass{
    public dummy(IFirst data){}
 }
```

Which kind of Objects does the dummy-Method accept then?

Comment: it accepts instances of all classes which implement the `IFirst` interface (including `A` and `B` and other implementations if they exist), and it also accepts `null`.

Comment: by the way, the method signature syntax is not correct and it won't compile.

Comment: You could have easily tested this before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, every Object that somehow implements the interface `IFirst`.
In your example that is `A` and also `B` since `B` extends `A` which is an `IFirst`, so `B` is also an `IFirst`.

Here's another example, the following structure:

```
interface Animal
class Dog implements Animal
class Cat implements Animal
class Husky extends Dog
class SmallDog extends Dog
class Chihuahua extends SmallDog
```

Makes sense that everything is of type `Animal` here :)